# Arraylist in arraylist

Tags: java, android

I wonder how I create arraylists dynamically and add them to an arraylist that holds all arraylists? I also wonder how I read from a dynamically created arraylist inside the main arraylist in a for-each loop?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: An `ArrayList` can contain any kind of objects, including another `ArrayList`. There's nothing special about that. What exactly are you having trouble with understanding?

Comment: I'm working with an app that need multiple touch inputs and I want to store all points of each user in an arraylist and then add it to a main arraylist. From the main arraylist I can then read all users touch inputs(each arraylist) and draw the path on the screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<Bar> innerList = new ArrayList<Bar>();
// add Bar objects to this list
List<List<Bar>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<Bar>>();
mainList.add(innerList); // adding innerList to mainList
for(List<Bar> listElement:mainList){
     // here listElement will give you an innerList
         for(Bar bar: listElement){
            // gives you a handle to each Bar element stored in
            // listElement
         }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In your example you have "innerList", but what if I want to create other innerlists during runtime? How do I set names to them? Can I call them by there id/number in the mainList?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but if you want to store something in `key-value` pair like `name-List` pair then use [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: I'm not sure either! :) This is complicated. What I meant was that each innerList has to be unique and then I guess I can't give them all the name "innerList"?

Comment: I think you are confusing reference variables to List with actual List objects !!!

Comment: I might do! Sorry I'm new to this! Can I access the innerLists content by looping throw the mainList by the index!?

Comment: Hmm I'm a little bit confused! I try to explain what I need. I have to store the X and Y Points for each user that draws on the screen. In my code so far I just have one arraylist to store the one users X and Y points. But I have to support multiple touch input whitch means that several user shuld be able to draw on the screen at the same time, and thats why I need to store them in arrayLists inside a main arrayList. During runtime I must read all this innerLists to be able to draw each path on the screen and do some checking. What about that!?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Guava's `Multimap` with a key of `Integer`.

[Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Specifically the [ArrayListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html)

`Multimap` will handle dynamically creating the inner `Lists` for you as needed so..

To add an element to any list within the set of lists:

```
Multimap<Integer, Bar> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
myMultimap.put(1, new Bar());

List<Bar> listAtIndex5 = myMultimap.get(5);
```

`Multimap` also provides the mechanism to iterate over all elements in all inner lists using `values`. So you can iterate over every element in the entire collection as such:

```
for (Bar bar: myMultimap.values()){
    // some work on bar
}
```

Comment: Why would you simulate a two-dimensional list with a `MultiMap`? There are no key/value pairs here...

Comment: @jlordo The "key" is the integer index of the outter list. When you do `mylist[5]` you are using a key of `5`. The reason I suggested this was to avoid logic checking to see if a list has already been created for a particular index and then having to create and add it prior to being able to add to this inner list. All the logic of creating the inner lists is provided and therefore much less risk of a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I see your point and revoked my -1. Anyway, I would prefer a simple `List<List<DataType>>`..

Comment: `Multimap<Integer, Bar>` would only have a single `List<Bar>` per key `Integer` not multiple `Lists`. And `Multimap.get` never returns `null` whereas if you had a `List<List<Bar>>` and did `outterList.get()` you could get a `null` or an `IndexOutOfRange`. So to add an element to the 3rd list in a `Multimap` you would do `map.get(2).add(myBar)`. This would never throw an exception. This is not as easy with a `List<List<Bar>>` because you have to handle the case of creating the inner `List`.

Comment: @jlordo thanks for accepting the point and totally understand your preference especially as `List<List<>>` is probably more readable for the non-guava initiated as opposed to `Multimap`. Cheers.

Comment: I use guava all of the time. It took me a minute to understand your approach, which will definitely work. The reason I prefer `List<List<>>` over your approach is the reliability of the indexes. If my outer list has the size 3, I will have indexes 0, 1 and 2. You could have any 3 (different) indexes...

Comment: point taken, you also lose the ability to simply `add` a `List` without knowing the next index.

Answer (score 1):

Like this..

```
ArrayList<DATA_TYPE> demo = new ArrayList<DATA_TYPE>();
for(DATA_TYPE i:demo)//foreach
{
System.out.println(i); 

}
```

Comment: You might wanna include the generics.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList< ArrayList< Foo > > masterList = new ArrayList< ArrayList< Foo > >( );

ArrayList< Foo > subList = new ArrayList< Foo >();

subList.add( new Foo( ) );
subList.add( new Foo( ) );

msterList.add( subList ) );

// repeat

for ( ArrayList< Foo > subList : masterList )
{
  for ( Foo foo : subList )
  {
    System.out.println( foo );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that the same way you would do it with any object.

to add to an array list:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> parent = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList<YourDataType> sub = new ArrayList<YourDataType>();
sub.add(new YourDataType());
parent.add(sub);
```

and when you want to read from that list:

```
for (ArrayList<YourDataType> list : parent){
     for(YourDataType obj : list){

        //access obj
      }

}
```

if you want to access a sub ArrayList at specific index:

```
int index = 5;
if(index < parent.size()){
    ArrayList<YourDataType> sub = parent.get(index);
}
```

Take a look here for a complete tutorial on Lists in Java:

- [The List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)
- [How To Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: But how do I set the names of the "sub" list during runtime?

Comment: you don't need to give them special variable names, because all of them well be appended to the parent ArrayList, and you will access them through it

Comment: OK, so I use an index to access the sub lists in the parent list? Could you add some code that show how?

Answer (score 0):

```
List list= new ArrayList();<\`pre`>
List list1= new ArrayList();
list1.add("Example1");
list1.add("Example2");
list.add(list1);
System.out.println(list);
```

U can find two arraylist which are added inside one more
<`pre`>

Comment: Generics were introduced with Java 1.5. Please use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using following lines

To declare the list dynamically

```
ArrayList<Object> childList = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> mainList=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

To add child lists to main list

```
  mainList.add(childList);
  mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
  mainList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
  ........
```

To Access the list inside a for loop,

```
for(ArrayList listobj: mainList){
   for(Object obj : listobj){
     //do something here
  }
}
```

If you want all your lists to be of same type you can use that type instead of Object in childlist declaration, However if you want all your child lists to be differrent it is better to use Object class directly.